# How do I find horizontal asymptotes of f(x)=7x+2/sqrt 9x^2+4

Tags: plotting

How do I find horizontal asymptotes of  f(x)=7x+2/sqrt 9x^2+4

Answer (score 5):

Since you are looking for horizontal asymptotes, I am guessing that the function was meant to be

```
f[x_] = (7 x + 2)/Sqrt[9 x^2 + 4];
```

Use [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) to find the two asymptotes

```
Limit[f[x], x -> #] & /@ {-Infinity, Infinity}

(* {-(7/3), 7/3} *)
```

To visualize

```
Plot[{7/3, f[x], -7/3}, {x, -5, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed[], Dashed},
 PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]